# Difference between add_references and add_column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys

```
 add_reference :books, :author
 add_column :books, :author_id, :integer
```

Here add references will create user_id column and add column is also creating user_id column in books table. What is the difference between them. What is the advantage of using references instead of column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TLDR

[*#add_column*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column) is meant for adding a column like the name suggests.

[*#add_reference*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) is meant as a shortcut for creating a column, index and foreign key at the same time.

## Explanation

In your example the only difference is the *index* on the column that will be created by *#add_reference* that defaults to `true`.

```
add_reference :books, :author
# equals
add_column :books, :author_id, :integer
add_index :books, :author_id
```

But if you would take the following line:

```
add_reference :books, :author, foreign_key: true
```

It would also create a foreign key constraint.

Furthermore if you would like to have every author be able to publish only one book you can set the *unique* constraint through *#add_reference* by doing the following:

```
add_reference :books, :author, null: false, index: {unique: true}, foreign_key: true
```

This requires every book to have an author and restraints the authors to have a maximum of one book.

The same can be done using *#add_column* by doing the following:

```
add_column :books, :author_id, :integer, null: false
add_index :books, :author_id, unique: true
add_foreign_key :books, :authors
```

Comment: Note that since Ruby on Rails 5.1 `:bigint` is used instead of `:integer`. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26266

Answer (score 0):

Both will generate the same columns when you run the migration.

> The first command adds a belongs_to :author relationship in your Book
>   model whereas the second does not. When this relationship is
>   specified, ActiveRecord will assume that the foreign key is kept in
>   the author_id column and it will use a model named Author to
>   instantiate the specific author.

The first command also adds an index on the new author_id column.

Comment: If I don't define foreign_key : true then ActiveRecord will assume that foreign key is kept in the author_id column. If I define it then ActiveRecord will surely know that author_id is id from author table. Am I right ?

Comment: @Suresh If you don't define `foreign_key: true` than no foreign key constraint will be created and the logic is only caught on application level.